# String replace with sources from dictionary does not work as expected

Tags: python

I am still at the learning process of Python. That is a code that is written in python that should encrypt the word or sentence the user inputs. It should change every letter or number to the next one.but it doesn't work. Like if I throw: **abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890**, it returns: **cceeggiikkmmooqqssuuwwyyaa2355679902**.

How can I solve this and why doesn't it work?

Here is the code:

```
   joka = raw_input("PLease enter a word:" )


def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

reps = {'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d', 'd':'e', 'e':'f', 'f':'g', 'g':'h', 'h':'i', 'i':'j', 'j':'k', 'k':'l', 'l':'m', 'm':'n', 'n':'o', 'o':'p', 'p':'q', 'q':'r', 'r':'s', 's':'t', 't':'u', 'u':'v', 'v':'w', 'w':'x', 'x':'y', 'y':'z', 'z':'a', '1':'2', '2':'3', '3':'4', '4':'5', '5':'6', '6':'7', '7':'8', '8':'9', '9':'0', '0':'1'}

j0ka = replace_all(joka, reps)
print j0ka
```

Comment: _Please help ASAP.._ This type of request doesn't work for voluntaries...

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: you should start from the other side: for every character in the input text find a replacement in your char map. not the other way. at this moment you substitute your substitutions.

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, I would be glad, if you could mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through the dictionary replacing only one letter each time. This breaks, since you would (if you would iterate in order) replace the first `a` with `b` but then replace the same (and following `b` already with `c`, ...

You do not see the effect since the order of your dictionary is not guaranteed.

You have now two alternative options:
1) Iterate through the string and look the letters up in the dictionary:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    return "".join([dic[t] for t in text])

reps = {'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d', 'd':'e', 'e':'f', 'f':'g', 'g':'h', 'h':'i', 'i':'j', 'j':'k', 'k':'l', 'l':'m', 'm':'n', 'n':'o', 'o':'p', 'p':'q', 'q':'r', 'r':'s', 's':'t', 't':'u', 'u':'v', 'v':'w', 'w':'x', 'x':'y', 'y':'z', 'z':'a', '1':'2', '2':'3', '3':'4', '4':'5', '5':'6', '6':'7', '7':'8', '8':'9', '9':'0', '0':'1'}
joka = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
j0ka = replace_all(joka, reps)
print j0ka
```

A long version of `replace_all`:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    replaced_letters = []
    for t in text:
        # iterate letter by letter through the string
        replaced_letters.append(dic[t])
    return "".join(replaced_letters)
```

Alternatively, you could use a little bit of mathematics to get to your result - each letter has a corresponding ASCII number.
Since what you are trying to achieve is close to the Cesar cipher, please check this resource for further information.
https://inventwithpython.com/chapter14.html